# Is "going to" possible in this case

Tags: future-constructions

> *We **are watching** a film tomorrow with Billy. He **is coming** to my house.*

This is the solution of the test, but could we choose

> *We **are going to** watch a film tomorrow  with  Billy. He **is coming** to my house.*

I think my solution can be ok because watching a film can be an arrangement (present continuous) or an intention (going to)
What do you think of my thinking

https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Future_tenses/Future*_will_-_be_going_to_-_present_continuous_ru249790sp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely fine. There are various ways of talking about future events, which only differ in nuance and shades of meaning.  As you have settled plans, it is correct to use "We are watching", but it is equally correct to use "We're going to watch".  Indeed, you could say "We will watch", that would be, perhaps, less *natural*, but not wrong, and you would hear native speakers using "will" in this context.

When talking about the future nothing is 100% certain. But you could use "We're watching" to indicate your greater confidence in your plans. Or "We're going to watch" to indicate your intention, but expressing less confidence.